# Bash parallel process on multiple input files, one output file

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I created a for loop that goes through multiple files and outputs the results into one file:

```
for x in /home/moleculo/x*; do ExtractOutCalls2.sh /home/Scripts/000 $x & done
```

So each of my input files starts with letter x, that's x* as input. Script takes each of those input files $x and outputs to file /home/Scripts/000

Now I have a question:

if this is done on a few thousand files, is it a good way to put like this?

also if I use multiple input files, but specify one output file, will this mean, that my output will won't be appended? If not, how to do it

Regards,
Irek

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your output file gets overwritten by each process. Make each script output to its own file, and once all the scripts are finished, concatenate the output:

```
i=0
for x in /home/moleculo/x* ; do
    ExtractOutCalls2.sh /home/Scripts/000 $x > OUT.$i &
    (( i++ ))
done
wait
cat OUT.* > OUT
rm OUT.*
```

You have to change the script to output to standard output instead of the file, or make it accept the name of the output file to be created.

Comment: I have the outptu as $argv[1] so this is doing the trick. And if this is done in parallel on couple of thousand of files, how does it look in terms of my cores? Won't it crash?

Comment: @Irek: Do you have thousands of cores? The disk I/O would probably be the bottleneck, though. Do not run thousands of processes.

Comment: Well actually, I do, but I just want to run it smart. But even if I do only 1 file input, will sth like xargs -P 4 -n 1 script.sh speed it? Or is it still no good, since I am going with only 1 file

Answer (score 1):

Often you can use the file - to designate stdout:

```
for x in /home/moleculo/x*; do ExtractOutCalls2.sh - $x & done
```

To avoid mixing output use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel ExtractOutCalls2.sh - {} ::: /home/moleculo/x* > output
```

Comment: The second one is better and cleaner.